# Picture placeholder in email

Tags: html, image, email

I'm using a simple PHP code to send a html via email.
The problem with the images is that they don't show because of the security issue they make. Gmail asks the user if he wants to display them.

How can I make a placeholder for the picture so when it doesn't show it will write in its place "please choose to display images" and have some border around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy in your `<img />` you just need to add the attribute `alt`. Per example:

```
<img alt="My text when no image is displayed" />
```

I just added a sample code here: http://jsfiddle.net/sMVgH/2/

HTH